# S3 bucket: Encountered unsupported property AccessControl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying create S3 buckets with access logs and so this is how my cloud formation template in yaml looks like

```
AccesslogBucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      BucketName: accesslog-dub-bucket
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  MyusecaseS3bucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    DependsOn:
      - AccesslogBucket
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      BucketName: my-usecase-s3-bucket
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: accesslog-dub-bucket
        LogFilePrefix: log-
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

But the cloudformation template is giving me the exception `Encountered unsupported property AccessControl` , I see that I am declaring the 'AccessControl' in correct section (i.e. in Properties section of Accesslogbucket) and it is a valid [property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-accesscontrol) , so I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Can someone point me to the issue here and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your `AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite` **under** `BucketEncryption` which is incorrect. It should be under `Properties`. Basically double check your indentations:

```
AccesslogBucket:
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite    
      BucketEncryption:       
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```